# Comparison of elements in a lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, lattice-orders

A lattice is made out of pairs $(A, C)$  where $A$ can be $0,1,2,3$ and $C$ is a subset of $\{g,i,p\}$.

Why can't there be a path between $(1,\{g,p\})$ and $(2,\{p\})$? Isn't the defintion of $a\leq c$

$$(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\leq(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m)$$

if $(a_1,a_2\ldots,a_n)$ if there exists an index $i$ such as $0\leq i\leq n$ and $a_0=c_0$, $a_1=c_1$, $\ldots$, $a_i<c_i$ or if $m>n$ if all previous elements are equal. Wouldn't this apply here since 
$1<2$?

Thanks!

Comment: To define a lattice, it's not sufficient to tell us what its elements are. What is the partial order on this lattice?

Comment: They didn't define it in the question but after trying it and comparing with the answers it seems that its $0 < 1 < 2 < 3$ and  $ set1 \space  < set2$ if $ set1 \space \epsilon \space set2$. Is it always defined like this?

Comment: No, it's not always defined like this. It's the most "natural" way, so to speak, but there's no "always" here. We can define any partial order we want, as long as it satisfies the definition of being a partial order. That's why I asked you what the order is. Moreover, there are several different ways to define a partial order on the cartesian product of two partially ordered sets. So you still need to clarify the question even more before anyone can address it.

Comment: That being said, most likely in this textbook exercise the usual order is used on the numbers and the ordering by inclusion is used on the subsets of a set. (Still, it had to mentioned somewhere; I can't believe that "they" didn't say anything about it.)